# How do I trap SIGQUIT properly in a bash script?

Tags: bash, unix, signals, exit, bash-trap

I can write shell scripts that trap `SIGINT` just fine, but I can't seem to trap `SIGQUIT`.

```
#!/bin/bash

function die {
    echo "Dying on signal $1"
    exit 0
}

trap 'die "SIGINT"' SIGINT
trap 'die "SIGQUIT"' SIGQUIT

while true; do
    echo "sleeping..."
    sleep 5
done
```

Executing this script and pressing `CTRL-C` has the desired effect, but pressing `CTRL-\` (which, as I understand, should trigger `SIGQUIT`) does nothing except print `^\` in the terminal. Why?

I have two running theories. The first is that the semantics of `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` are different such that `SIGQUIT` only gets sent to the child process `sleep`, while `SIGINT` gets sent to both the child process and the parent bash process. If this is the case, where is it documented?

My second theory is that bash not only ignores (i.e., has a no-op handler for) `SIGQUIT` by default (as the man page suggests), but does not allow it to be trapped at all. This theory overlaps with the first theory, since it could be the case that `SIGQUIT` is going to both parent and child, but the parent (`bash`) just can't trap it. If this is the case, is there *any* way to trap `SIGQUIT` in a bash script?... perhaps some `shopt` I can set?

Edit: this is on Ubuntu 10.10 in gnome-terminal 2.32.0 running bash 4.1.5, and yes `^\` is configured to issue SIGQUIT (as reported by `stty -a` and confirmed by issuing `^\` SIGQUITs to other programs like `ping`).

UPDATE:
I just discovered that the problem must be due somehow to gnome-terminal. If I run this script from a virtual console (i.e., `ctrl-alt-f1` to get out of X), it traps SIGQUIT perfectly fine when I press `^\`. Same bash and everything, so the only difference must be the terminal emulator. So now my question becomes: how can I configure gnome-terminal to behave like the virtual console in this respect? I `diff`'d the outputs of `stty -a` in the virtual console and in gnome-terminal, and while there are differences, nothing seems immediately relevant (e.g., they both have `quit = ^\;`).

UPDATE 2:
Another experiment. Simply execute `$ sleep 60` in gnome-terminal; press `^\` and the signal goes uncaught. Now execute `$ sleep 60` in the virtual console; press `^\` and the signal *is* caught -- the process prints `Quit` and exits. But now run `$ ping google.com` in gnome-terminal and press `^\` -- the signal is caught and handled as expected. So there is something weird about gnome-terminal such that SIGQUIT can be caught by some programs, but not by others, even if those other others *do* catch it when invoked from the virtual console. Perhaps I should just upgrade my gnome-terminal.

Comment: This works for me as expected on Ubuntu 11.04, bash 4.2.8. What operating system and bash version are you using?

Comment: works for me too. 
sleeping...
^\Quit (core dumped)
Dying on signal SIGQUIT

Comment: there are numerous posting here about `trap`. Check them. Also, I think it is possible that your `stty` is not setup the way you expect for handling `^\`. I'm almost sure that SIGKILL is the only signal that cannot be trapped. Check the doc. Good luck!

Comment: your script works for me on OS X 10.6.7, bash: 4.2.0(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin10.7.0)

Comment: What is your output from `stty -a` for the quit= ? Should be `^\\`

Comment: This is on Ubuntu 10.10, bash 4.1.5, and the output of `stty -a` is as follows. ^\ definitely works for me for sending SIGQUIT to other programs (e.g., `ping`, which responds to SIGQUIT by printing a status line).

    speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
    intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
    swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
    lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only assume that this was some sort of bug in gnome-terminal 2.32.0; I have since upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04, with gnome-terminal 2.32.1 (and bash 4.2.8) and SIGQUIT is now trapped as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I observe the same behavior on Fedora 19 with XFCE: according to `ps s`, bash in the xfce4-terminal has SIGQUIT ignored, running `yes >/dev/null &` and then `ps s` shows that even a subprocess has SIGQUIT ignored. When I (from the same terminal) run `ssh localhost`, the shell in the ssh session also has SIGQUIT ignored, but `yes >/dev/null &` has not.

Given the above comment which mentions gnome-terminal, I would guess the bug is in the common part of the two terminals: the `vte` library. Mine is `vte-0.28.2-9.fc19.x86_64`.